# Circular people images with presence icon

Tags: css, people-search, presence-indication

We would like our SharePoint employee search to look similar to (our version of) Lync/Skype, which uses circular images:

[image]

However, [these](http://www.sharepointcolumn.com/lync-presence-indicators-in-sharepoint-2013/) are the options provided by SharePoint, which uses the following PNG to visualize presence:

[image]

We have the CSS needed to make our employee images rounded with a discreet border, but is there a quick win for getting the desired rounded overlay icon for presence?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the actual Skype icons? (Green check-mark) (Yellow clock). Or just want the SharePoint presence PNG to appear rounded?

Comment: @Christoffer Whatever is cheapest in terms of development time, and as long as the necessary status information is conveyed. I'm not sure what we lose if the small-ish asterisks get cropped. What do they signify?

Comment: Asterisks = the stars in the bottom right hand corner. I am not sure what they mean or if we can afford to crop them.

Comment: The Asterisks indicates that Out of Office is activated in their Outlook. I think that Danny provided an good answer. :) Or you could just add a border radius (might be tricky as SharePoint uses CSS positions to show the correct icon. | .ms-spimn-imgSize-10x10 {
   border-radius:10px;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: there are also old Blogs around showing you how to use SharePoint native code; but as I recall they are tight to Lync installed on the local machine (*I could be wrong here*)

---

#### The Modern Fabric way

Microsoft has developed their own version of the Bootstrap Library : **Fabric** (aka Office UI Fabric)

https://dev.office.com/fabric#/

It includes the styling to create **Persona** cards

If you do not want to do all the HTML & Javascript yourself,
you can add the **FabricJS Components**  Library

(*if you are doing React there is also a React version somewhere*)

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/blob/master/ghdocs/components/Persona.md

[image]